# List all environment variables in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

The `set` command will list some variables, but but not all.

`echo %CD%` will list the current directory variable but it's not included in the `set` listing.

Is there a command that will list all variable names and values?

Comment: Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

As `set /?` documents (emphasis mine):

> If Command Extensions are enabled, then **there are several dynamic
> environment variables that can be expanded but which don't show up in
> the list of variables displayed by SET.**  These variable values are
> computed dynamically each time the value of the variable is expanded.
> If the user explicitly defines a variable with one of these names, then
> that definition will override the dynamic one described below:
>
> %CD% - expands to the current directory string.
>
> %DATE% - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.
>
> %TIME% - expands to current time using same format as TIME command.
>
> %RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.
>
> %ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value
>
> %CMDEXTVERSION% - expands to the current Command Processor Extensions
> version number.
>
> %CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original command line that invoked the
> Command Processor.
>
> %HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER% - expands to the highest NUMA node number
> on this machine.

So if you want to see the value of the dynamic environment variables, you have to explicitly access them.

Comment: ah ! i didnt think of trying the built in help oops

thanks :D